# Where does `this` go in a x64 thiscall?

Tags: c++, calling-conventions

So I understand that [`thiscall` doesn't really exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) in x64 programming. However, I can't really find any definitive explanation as to *where* the `this` pointer is put to be passed to the callee.

Is a x64 `thiscall` like a true `cdecl` call, where `this` is put on to the 'stack' last (on both GCC and MSVC compilers)?

**EDIT:** Running through GDB, it appears so. `rdi` held the `this` pointer and `rsi` held the one parameter that particular method had. Is this how it always works?

Comment: I couldn't find a proper reference for it, but to my knowledge the `this` parameter is usually treated as the first argument of the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no explicit convention for passing a `this` pointer. Since it is passed into the function as a hidden additional argument, it will be passed using the convention for arguments. Which argument is presumably left to the compiler designer.

There are only two calling conventions in use, effectively Windows and Unix. In each case functions with a small number of arguments (4 or 6) pass all arguments in registers. That still doesn't tell you which has the `this` pointer.

I'm drawing the distinction between the officially sanctioned calling convention (which says that the first 4 or 6 arguments go in specified registers), and whatever unofficial convention is used for choosing which argument should represent the `this` pointer. In most cases it will probably be the first argument (which matches your experience), but it may not always be so.

Comment: Sorry I'm just now seeing this. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 6):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

"the [this pointer] is passed as an implicit first parameter." So in X64 __fastcall convention [this pointer] should always be set in the RCX register.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! That has been my experience too.